# Roblox Lua DataStore not saving and loading player data correctly

Tags: database, module, lua, roblox, datastore

I'm working on a Roblox game, and I'm having trouble with saving and loading player data using DataStore. The script I'm using is supposed to save players' Coins and Gems values when they leave the game and load them when they join, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's the code I'm using:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local playerDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayerData")

local function createLeaderstats(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local Coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    Coins.Name = "Coins"

    local Gems = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    Gems.Name = "Gems"

    return leaderstats
end

local function savePlayerData(player)
    local leaderstats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
    if leaderstats then
        local data = {
            Coins = leaderstats.Coins.Value,
            Gems = leaderstats.Gems.Value
        }
        local playerUserId = tostring(player.UserId)
        local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
            playerDataStore:SetAsync(playerUserId, data)
        end)
        if not success then
            warn("Failed to save data for player: " .. player.Name .. ". Error: " .. errorMessage)
        end
    end
end

local function loadPlayerData(player)
    local leaderstats = createLeaderstats(player)
    local playerUserId = tostring(player.UserId)
    local data

    local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
        data = playerDataStore:GetAsync(playerUserId)
    end)

    if success then
        if data and type(data) == "table" and data.Coins and data.Gems then
            leaderstats.Coins.Value = data.Coins
            leaderstats.Gems.Value = data.Gems
        else
            leaderstats.Coins.Value = 0
            leaderstats.Gems.Value = 0
        end
    else
        warn("Failed to load data for player: " .. player.Name .. ". Error: " .. errorMessage)
        leaderstats.Coins.Value = 0
        leaderstats.Gems.Value = 0
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    loadPlayerData(player)
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    savePlayerData(player)
end)
```

The structure of my Lua script is designed to work with various modules and RemoteEvents in my Roblox game. These dependencies and the way they interact with each other are essential for the proper functioning of the game. Therefore, modifying the structure or the way these modules and RemoteEvents are used could lead to unexpected issues or break the intended behavior of the game.

I implemented a Lua script in my Roblox game to save and load player data, specifically Coins and Gems, using DataStore. I've double-checked the script and ensured that it is being triggered when players join and leave the game.

Comment: Did you try printing the loaded date? The code looks fine to me.